# Delete Cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to delete cells in a `UICollectionview` like I did in `UITableview`.

With `UITableview`, I did it this way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:folder];
        NSArray *fileListAct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:nil];
        NSString *dataFile = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileListAct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dataFile error:NULL];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

I want to achieve the same in a `UICollectionview`. I started like this, but it doesn't work:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editActive) {
        NSLog(@"EditCalled");
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:folder];
        NSArray *fileListAct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:nil];
        NSString *dataFile = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileListAct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dataFile error:NULL];

        [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }

}
```

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

**EDIT**

I found the issue.

I used

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

instead of

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Stupid typo.